# dModule not found: Error: Can't resolve '@apollo-client' in '/Users

Tags: apollo-client

My app doesn't load and my terminal shows the following error when i try running

```
npm run develop
```

```
[1] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@apollo-client' in '/Users/coding/bootcamp/personal-projects/Healing/client/src/utils'
[1] 
[1] webpack compiled with 1 error
^C[1] cd client && npm start exited with code SIGINT
[0] cd server && npm run watch exited with code SIGINT
```

Also i have a mutations.js and a queries.js file in a utils folder.

I started with mutations.js and was able to add patients, get all patients and a single patient with graphql entering inputs in the form from concurrently running the app at the root.
When i added query to (Home)index.js file the application started the error message.

### queries.js file looks like this:

```
import { gql } from '@apollo-client';

export const QUERY_PATIENTS = gql`
     query patients {
         patients {
         _id
         patientname
         age
       }
   }
`;

export const QUERY_PATIENT = gql`
    query patient($id: ID!) {
        patient(id: $id) {
            _id
            patientname
            age
        }
     }
 `;
```

### Here is my index.jsx file where i am using the query:

```
import React from 'react';
import PatientList from '../PatientList';
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { QUERY_PATIENTS } from '../../utils/queries';

const Home = () => {

    const { data } = useQuery(QUERY_PATIENTS);
    const patients = data?.patients || [];

    return (
        <main>
            <h3>This is the new homepage</h3>
            <div>
                <PatientList
                    patients={patients}
                />
            </div>
        </main>
    )
};

export default Home;
```

### Here is my package.json client:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.7.10",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

### Here is my package.json root level:

```
{
  "name": "healing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "develop": "concurrently \"cd server && npm run watch\" \"cd client && npm start\"",
    "install": "cd server && npm i && cd ../client && npm i",
    "seed": "cd server && npm run seed",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Saidou25/Healing.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^8.0.1"
  },
```

### Here is a link to the repository:

```
https://github.com/Saidou25/Healing.git
```